# Laravel Virgin: Disable/mock database connection when testing model mutators that utilize relationships

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following models:

- `Grid.php`

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Rover;

class Grid extends Model
{
    /**
     * Table Name
     */
    protected $table='grid';

    public function rovers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rover::class);
    }
}
```

- `Rover.php`

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Model\Grid;

class Rover extends Model
{

    /**
     * Table Name
     */
    protected $table='rover';

    public function grid()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Grid::class);
    }

    public function setGridPosXValue($value)
    {
        $Grid = $this->grid()->first();
        $width = $Grid->width;
        if($value < 0 || $value > $width){
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("X is out of grid bounds");
        }

        $this->attributes['x']=$value;
    }

    public function setGridPosYValue($value)
    {
        $Grid = $this->grid()->first();
        $height = $Grid->height;

        if($value < 0 || $value > $height){
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Y is out of grid bounds");
        }

        $this->attributes['y']=$value;
    }
}
```

And I want to test the Rover's mutator with theese tests:

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Model\Rover;
use App\Model\Grid;
use Mockery;

define("TEST_ROVEL_SUCCESS_VAL",3);
define("TEST_ROVEL_NEGATIVE_VAL",-1);


class RoverModelTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSetGridPosXValueThrowsExceptionWhenNegative(){
        $this->markTestSkipped('To be implemented');
    }

    public function testSetGridPosXValueThrowsExceptionWhenOverWidth(){
        $rover = new Rover();
        $grid = new Grid();
        $grid->width=5;
        $grid->height=5;
        $rover->grid=$grid;

        $this->expectException(\InvalidArgumentException::class);
        $rover->setGridPosXValue(TEST_ROVEL_NEGATIVE_VAL);

    }

    public function testSetGridPosXValueThorwsExceptionOnNormal(){
        $rover = new Rover();
        $grid = new Grid();

        $grid->width=5;
        $grid->height=5;

        $rover->grid=$grid;
        try {
            $rover->setGridPosXValue(TEST_ROVEL_SUCCESS_VAL);
            $this->assertEquals($rover->x,TEST_ROVEL_SUCCESS_VAL);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $this->fail("No exception should be thrown when setting a correct value.");
        }
    }
}
```

So when I run the tests I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

SFF                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 125 ms, Memory: 18.00 MB

There were 2 failures:

1) Tests\Unit\RoverModelTest::testSetGridPosXValueThrowsExceptionWhenOverWidth
Failed asserting that exception of type "Illuminate\Database\QueryException" matches expected exception "InvalidArgumentException". Message was: "SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "laravel" (SQL: select * from "grid" where "grid"."id" is null limit 1)" at
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:46
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/PostgresConnector.php:33
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php:182
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:918
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:943
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:399
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:325
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:657
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:624
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:333
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2124
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2112
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2598
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2113
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:521
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php:505
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php:77
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:23
/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/Relation.php:386
/var/www/html/app/Model/Rover.php:23
/var/www/html/tests/Unit/RoverModelTest.php:28
.

2) Tests\Unit\RoverModelTest::testSetGridPosXValueThorwsExceptionOnNormal
No exception should be thrown when setting a correct value.

/var/www/html/tests/Unit/RoverModelTest.php:44

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 2, Failures: 2, Skipped: 1.
```

Meaning that the tests hit a misconfigured database connection.

So how I can set a "fake" database connection in order not to use any database at all when testing? The reason why is because I want to do a unit testing instead of an integration testing.

In my case I want the code not to hit the db connection and test the logic that the mutator has without writing into the database at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `$this->grid()->first()` instead of `$this->grid` which forces the use of the database connection to get the grid.

You can probably achieve what you need using a partial mock:

```php
class RoverModelTest extends TestCase
{
    private $rover;

    // Avoid code duplication
    protected function setUp() : void { 
        parent::setUp();
        $this->rover = $this->getMockBuilder(Rover::class)
                 ->setMethods('grid')
                 ->getMock();        
        $grid = new Grid();
        $grid->width=5;
        $grid->height=5;
        $this->rover->expects($this->any())->method('grid')->willReturn(collect([$grid]));

    }

    public function testSetGridPosXValueThrowsExceptionWhenNegative(){
        $this->markTestSkipped('To be implemented');
    }

    public function testSetGridPosXValueThrowsExceptionWhenOverWidth(){
        $this->expectException(\InvalidArgumentException::class);
        $this->rover->setGridPosXValue(TEST_ROVEL_NEGATIVE_VAL);
    }

    public function testSetGridPosXValueThorwsExceptionOnNormal(){       
        try {
            $this->rover->setGridPosXValue(TEST_ROVEL_SUCCESS_VAL);
            $this->assertEquals($this->rover->x,TEST_ROVEL_SUCCESS_VAL);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $this->fail("No exception should be thrown when setting a correct value.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Or I can use the `$this->grid`.

Comment: Yes, that would be the simple solution but I don't think this code is untestable so personally I don't like the idea of modifying testable code just to get the tests to work. However it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I also wonder where the function `collect` is located as well, is a standart Php function?

Comment: No it's a laravel helper function to create a new [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections) which is what the query builder also returns (more or less)

Comment: So to not down that eloquent as seen in this piece of [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships) return a new collection right?

Comment: Technically relationships return [eloquent collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections) as results but these inherit from the base collection so using a base collection in the mock object should have it behave identically in most cases

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195463/discussion-between-dimitrios-desyllas-and-apokryfos).